# Can i make state duplicate in state diagram?

Tags: state, diagram

I have state diagram for an application, and one of the states should be duplicate.
can i duplicate the state in state diagram?

since it is necessary to be.

Comment: One state can be call back or loop back to itself.

Comment: Please give an example of what you need like what is your requirement ?

Comment: user either register or not,
after that some processes should be for rigesterd users,
then some processes for both,
finally there is process for registered ,
can i duplicate the process whitch is for both since it allocated between two processes fr registered.